# Get values greater than x and lower than x in separate arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in PHP with some variables for example (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) I want to get two separate arrays one with all the variables lower than `$idusuario` (which might be 2, for example), for example the array `1` would have only one value "1" and array `2` would have "3,4,5,6,7".

PS: My php variables are:

```
$arrayfinal[] --> the array I want to divide
$idusuario --> the variable which separates both arrays
```

Comment: So you don't want the matching value in either array.... look at [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easily:

```
$lessThan = array();
$greaterThan = array();

foreach($arrayFinal as $element){   // loop initial array
  if($element < $idusuario){     // if element < idusuario, add to first array
     $lessThan[] = $element;
  }else{
     $greaterThan[] = $element;  // add to second array
```

Exclude and remove $idusuario

```
    $lessThan = array();
    $greaterThan = array();

    foreach($arrayFinal as $element){   // loop initial array
      if($element < $idusuario){     // if element < idusuario, add to first array
         $lessThan[] = $element;
      }elseif($element > $idusuario){
         $greaterThan[] = $element;  // add to second array
      }
   }
```

Comment: This will add `$idusuario` to the second array. It should be excluded instead.

Comment: Want to exclude it, then change the `} else {` to `} else if ($element > $idusuario) {`

Comment: He never mentioned not including $idusuario

Comment: yes he did. $idusuario is 2 in the example and... "and array 2 would have "3,4,5,6,7""

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-filter.php) instead of `foreach`:

```
$smaller = array_filter($array, function($value) use ($separator) {
    return $value < $separator;
});
$bigger = array_filter($array, function($value) use ($separator) {
    return $value > $separator;
});
```

But I'd guess the `foreach` approach is faster.